# Count the number of arrays that are used

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have the following:

```
var nr_0 = new Array("","","");
var nr_1 = new Array("","","");
var nr_2 = new Array("","","");
var nr_3 = new Array("","","");
var nr_4 = new Array("","","");
```

and so on...

is there a way to count how many arrays are used. so in this case it schould come out a string with the number 5

thank you.

Comment: Use arrays instead of variable variables. PS: dear answerers, please remember, that every time you suggest someone to use `eval` a kitten dies. PPS: no, it's not possible to use a global object in this case.

Comment: What does "used" mean? Declared? Or actually made use of? (And why do you want a *count* to produce a string?)

Comment: The answer you need to hear, is probably not the answer you are waiting for.  Can you explain what you are doing?  What you need to accomplish?

Comment: @zerkms as an anecdote in old browsers you could override the `Array` function itself and hook on creating arrays incrementing a counter - this stopped pretty quickly as people abused it for attack vectors (hooking on `[]` being executed to read sensitive data), fun times.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That was going to be my PPPS, but you were too quick!

Comment: i want to use the same page over and over again. sometimes i have 5 arrays and sometimes i have 20.

Comment: i could count them my selve and put the answer in a srting my selve. but i want it to be as easy as possible for me :)

Comment: @RonnyHabets " as easy as possible for me" --- so now it's so easy so that you cannot handle it. I find it funny :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them into 1 array instead of multiple variables :

```
var nr = [
    new Array("","",""),
    new Array("","",""),
    new Array("","",""),
    new Array("","",""),
    new Array("","","")
];
console.log(nr.length);
```

BTW, this is more elegant:

```
var nr = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
];
console.log(nr.length);
```

Comment: "atomic variable" -- what does this term mean?

Comment: Edited. I meant : multiple variables handling only one array each

Comment: is it posible to use the .lenght on a multiple array? like this

Comment: if (nr[0].lenght = 3),